# SSIS Package display MessageBox in Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2014

I have a SSIS package task that is displaying messageboxes even those that code in the task is commented out when I run it. How do I stop that?

Comment: Is this just a matter of opening up the Script Task code and choosing Build then closing and saving the change? Maybe the code change hasn't been compiled or something?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable interactive mode in the package. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922624/how-do-i-disable-interactive-message-boxes-from-inside-an-ssis-package) question on Stack Overflow should point you in the right direction and the documentation for this property on Tech Net can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.interactivemode%28SQL.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Alternatively, try right-clicking on the solution, Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Interactive Mode. Set this to false.

Comment: InteractiveMode is set to False

Comment: Can you post more information about the SSIS package such as scripts and tasks?

Answer (score 0):

This was very strange. I had a MessageBox line commented out in my script task but it was still executing. Once I took that out, it stopped displaying the MessageBox.

Done ask me why it was executing a commented out line of code.

//MessageBox("...")

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done many times over is to forget to compile the script executable and then compile the project before testing.  After going back and doing that, the results are as expected.  It plagues me to this day.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196806)